# What form the verb after besides?

Tags: verb-forms

I wonder if we can use *'besides+to+verb'* or if it is only *'besides+verb+ing'*

> Besides to get such data, we must also ...
>
> besides getting such data, we must ....

Which one is correct ? What is the most formal sentences among the two ? Is *'besides'* adapted here ?

Answer (score 1):

True as said by Josh. The preposition *besides* in such structure takes gerund after it and not an infinitive verb.

> [besides](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/besides_1) - *in addition to someone or something; except for someone or something.*

Check the examples given by OALD, it takes the gerund after it.

Also note that, *besides* can also go this way in your case...

> *We must also [whatever your concern is] besides (such) data.*

Other ways of using *besides* are [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/besides?q=besides).